# How to visualize relationships between nodes in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using oracle apex 21.2. I want to create a chart which show the connections between sites so which type of chart I can use to show the relationships between sites. The following is the structure of my tables.

| Sites table |
| --- |
| ID PK |
| Name |

| Link types table |
| --- |
| ID PK |
| Name |

| Site connections table |
| --- |
| Connection ID PK |
| Site ID 1 FK references sites(ID) |
| Link ID FK references link types(ID) |
| Site ID 2 FK references sites(ID) |

Comment: Apex is not a graphical tool but js libraries can be included.  I suggest you look for a javascript library that does what you want and then integrate that in your apex application